# Should I say "they're my brother and sister" or "that's my brother and sister"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, relative-pronouns, compound-subjects

This is a stand alone sentence, used as an exercise in learning Mandarin Chinese. It has no context. I feel that it is more natural to say "that's my brother and sister", in English. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are fine—but context will determine which is more appropriate.

For instance:

> "Who are those two people?"
>   "*They're my brother and sister.*

Here, you are answering a question.

---

But:

> I pointed at the two of them and said, "*That's my brother and sister.*"

Here, you are describing something you've introduced yourself in a demonstrative way.

Comment: @Natalie I don't think there's any problem adding clarification to a question—so long as it's not edited in a way that it makes existing answers confusing. Maybe add something like a **Note** clarification at the end.